# What does "coherence" means in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> These two types of democracy represent coherent and therefore ideal
> polities maximising the basic ideas of either majoritarian or
> power-sharing politics. It is easy to identify Switzerland and the UK
> as two polities that correspond to most criteria of one of the models.
> The UK systematically favours the logic of majority rule: Competitive
> elections between two main parties based on one major political
> division (left-right) lead to clear parliamentary majorities. The
> winner-takes-all rule makes parliamentary majorities sensitive to even
> small changes in the electorate’s preferences; the losing party
> becomes Her Majesty’s Official Opposition. Because of its
> parliamentary majority, the executive cabinet is empowered to realise
> its policy programme, as long as there is no successful vote of no
> confidence, which may necessitate resignation and an early election.
> Power is concentrated among the parliamentary majority and the
> cabinet. The House of Lords has few competencies; almost all
> legislative power belongs to the House of Commons. The latter may
> change constitutional documents in the same way as any other laws,
> with very few judicial constraints. One may speak of a nearly
> ‘sovereign’ parliament, with the main exceptions of devolution of
> power to Scotland and, Wales and Northern Ireland, and of more some
> independence given to the Bank of England. A similar **coherence of
> elements**, but with the opposite goal of power-sharing and negotiating
> politics, is found in the consensus model of Switzerland. Lately, both
> Switzerland and the UK have somewhat moved away from the ideal models
> in becoming less consensual, the first, and less majoritarian, the
> latter.
>
> *-Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I do not understand what does "coherence of elements" refer to here.

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coherence) coherence means:

> the situation when the parts of something fit together in a natural or reasonable way:

And According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coherence)

> systematic or logical connection or consistency

I interpret this as: the author refers to the consistemcy of elements in the politics of United Kingdom. Such as the connection between authorities, the cabinet and parliament and etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Coherence" is being used pretty much according to the M-W dictionary definition: "systematic or logical connection or consistency".

The addition of the word "elements" is pretty much redundant - it merely underlines that the policies of (almost) any political party are complex/multiple.

Put together, this is basically talking about the inevitable situation where different parts of a political system, whether that be partners in a coalition, or the different "Houses" within the UK parliament have different priorities and goals. Sometimes those goals are at odds, but when they are not, then things are seen to be "coherent".